# SQL add 1 day to all dates between two values

Tags: sql, oracle

Statement:
Rides between `20-12-2016` and `31-12-2016` are delayed one day. How do I write the SQL query for this?

I currently have:

```
UPDATE Rides
SET (SELECT * FROM Rides WHERE Date BETWEEN '20-12-2016' AND '31-12-2016') = [SOMETHING]
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?)

Comment: if that's mysql, the dates are totally wrong and will not work. "date math" will only work on dates that are formatted with `yyyy-mm-dd`. and you cannot assign a value TO a query. you only extract values FROM a query.

Comment: I'm using oracle sorry forgot to mention

Comment: Please do not use string literals for date values. Oracle will implicitly call `TO_DATE()` with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format mask - if this does not match then the query will fail. Worse, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so any user can change it for their session and then the query can break for that user (and work for the other users) without changing the text of the query (making it very hard to debug).

Answer (score 3):

This works in Oracle:

```
UPDATE rides
  SET date_field = date_field + 1
  WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2016-12-20' AND '2016-12-31';
```

I refer to the field to update as `date_field` since it is a bad practice to name fields/columns with a reserved keyword.

Comment: @ EvilTeach Maybe so, I just could not bring myself to update field which is a keyword -- VERY BAD PRACTICE.

Comment: @ EvilTeach I added the comment. Good call.

Comment: Sometimes you inherit bad table/column names from those who have gone before.  It's just something you have to deal with.   You can put double quotes around a column name to allow mixed case names.   It may make the query seem a bit cleaner as it doesn't look exactly like a keyword.

Comment: @ EvilTeach I considered mentioning the "double-quote" option, but I found that adds complexity to Java in that when you request the data from that column, you must be exact, i.e. it is NOT case-indifferent. I tend to follow best-practices in an effort to Keep-It-Simple-Sir. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Please do not use string literals for date values. Oracle will implicitly call `TO_DATE()` with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format mask - if this does not match then the query will fail. Worse, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so any user can change it for their session and then the query can break for that user (and work for the other users) without changing the text of the query (making it very hard to debug).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following for `Oracle`:

```
Update  Rides
Set     Date = Date + 1
Where   Date Between '2016-12-20' And '2016-12-31'
```

Comment: Please do not use string literals for date values. Oracle will implicitly call `TO_DATE()` with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as the format mask - if this does not match then the query will fail. Worse, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is a session parameter so any user can change it for their session and then the query can break for that user (and work for the other users) without changing the text of the query (making it very hard to debug).